# interning empty string error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Currently, in my request model I have:

```
belongs_to :requestor, :class_name => 'User'
```

So the requestor is the current_user.

Problem is when the `current_user` clicks the create button to submit a form for a request, all of the attributes get updated to the database that are in the form.
But since `requestor_id` is not a value to fill out in the form, that brings back a value of null in the database when the new request record is created.
What I want is an integer (which equates to the primary key of the Users table) updated in the `requestor_id` column in the request table when the user clicks the create button.
So I thought that maybe adding a `requestor_id` as a symbol in the params for the create action would solve that:

```
def create_common
  @a = Request.new
    b = @a.requestor_id
  @resource = yield params[:contact + "#{b}".to_sym]
  self.resource = @resource
```

But instead it returns the following error:

> interning empty string

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you want to assign the current_user's id as the requestor id to the Request model?

```
# assign values passed in via form
@request = Request.new(params[:request])
# assign current_user to request
@request.requestor = current_user
# save the request
@request.save!
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This ended up working:
@resource.requestor = current_user 

The only thing I'm not sure is how by doing what was done above does that assign the user primary key to the requestor_id. I would think that we would have to specify requestor_id, but that obviously isn't the case. Any insight into how this works? thanks.

Comment: In Rails, when you assign an object to relationship (eg: current_user which is a User object to requestor), it automatically extracts the ID of the object (in this case User's ID) and assigns it to the foreign key based on the relationship (in this case requestor_id).  You can find detailed source code of this functionality within the ActiveRecord gem.

Answer (score 6):

I kept getting this error. I traced it to very simple code and reproduced in the console with this:

```
ruby-1.8.7-p174 :084 > a = 'fred'
 => "fred" 
ruby-1.8.7-p174 :085 > a.to_sym
 => :fred 
ruby-1.8.7-p174 :086 > a = ''
 => "" 
ruby-1.8.7-p174 :087 > a.to_sym
ArgumentError: interning empty string
    from (irb):87:in `to_sym'
    from (irb):87
```

Comment: This behaviour occurs only on 1.8. On 1.9, you get `:""` instead. Occasionally I've written code that works on 1.9, but not on 1.8.

Comment: Thanks for this.  Was coding with ruby 1.8.7 and was baffled by this error, never seen it before.  Saved me some headache.

Comment: Thank you. This is the only place I found this explanation, for a non-rails Ruby 1.8 problem.

Answer (score 2):

Can you not just pass the Request the **current_user** when you create it?

```
@req = Request.new(:requestor => current_user)
```

I am not quite sure what the yield params statement is meant to be doing,

Answer (score 0):

I had a '.' in an error message similar to:

```
 errors.add('You entered a non-supported widget.')
```

and was getting the "interning empty string error"

This post saved me:

http://www.tonyamoyal.com/2009/10/20/interning-empty-string-error-in-ruby-on-rails/

Simply changing to:

```
 errors.add('You entered a non-supported widget')
```

fixed it. Rails 2.3.4 and Ruby 1.8.5